# Why is my locally-created script not allowed to run under the RemoteSigned execution policy?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, code-signing, executionpolicy

> Since this question continues to attract responses that are either
> refuted by the question body or don't address the actual problem,
> **please read this simple summary** of what you need to know:
>
> - **This is *not* a "Why won't my default installation of PowerShell run scripts?" question.**
> - **This is *not* a "Why won't my installation of PowerShell run scripts downloaded from the internet?" question.**
> - **The question is why the `RemoteSigned` execution policy is preventing script execution when it shouldn't.**
> - **`RemoteSigned` is the *only* execution policy I want to use.**  I am aware that other, less-restrictive policies are available.  If
>   those policies were acceptable substitutes I would have just used them
>   instead and this question wouldn't exist.
> - **The execution policy is *already* set to `RemoteSigned`.**  Changing it from `RemoteSigned` to `RemoteSigned` is not a solution.
> - **The script file is created and stored locally.**
> - **The script file is not blocked.**  The script file was never blocked (see previous point).
> - **The script file cannot be unblocked** because there is nothing to unblock  (see previous point).
> - **The script file is (attempted to be) executed by an administrator.**
> - **Windows PowerShell is the only application involved.** Not Windows PowerShell ISE nor Command Prompt nor any other tools or
>   editors are relevant.
> - **The cause of the problem has *already* been identified** (see accepted answer).  After nearly 8 years, I think all other obvious
>   explanations, whether applicable or not, have been posted, too. If
>   you think otherwise then **please read the question and existing
>   answers *in their entirety* before adding yours.**

---

I am using Windows PowerShell 2.0 on 64-bit Windows 7 Professional. I have a script on my desktop that causes the following error when I try to run it:

```
File C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Script.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Script.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system.  Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details..
At line:1 char:54
+ C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\TestGetWindowsUpdateLog.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I am both a domain administrator and a local administrator, and if I run `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`, I can see that the Group Policy Object I created to configure PowerShell is correctly applying the `RemoteSigned` execution policy at the machine level:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy    RemoteSigned
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

I created the script myself in Notepad, and used the [Sysinternals](https://www.sysinternals.com/)' [Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/streams) utility and the File Properties dialog to confirm that the script is not being treated as having come from the internet. If I copy the script to a network share on a domain server, then it's allowed to execute. If I run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine` then the local script is still not allowed to execute, which makes sense since the execution policy at the `MachinePolicy` scope will take precedence.

As documented by `about_Execution_Policies`([current](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies); [at time of question](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd347641.aspx)), the `RemoteSigned` policy means:

> - Scripts can run.
> - Requires a digital signature from a trusted publisher on scripts and configuration files that are downloaded from the Internet
>   (including e-mail and instant messaging programs).
> - Does not require digital signatures on scripts that you have run and that you have written on the local computer (not downloaded from
>   the Internet).
> - Risks running unsigned scripts from sources other than the Internet and signed, but malicious, scripts.

My script is not signed, but since it is both created and executed locally, it should satisfy the third bullet point above. Therefore...

- Why is my script not being allowed to run?
- Why does PowerShell complain that my script "is not digitally signed" when that requirement should only apply to files from the Internet?
- Why does PowerShell no longer care about the script not being signed when it's run from a network share?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally tracked this down to [.NET Code Access Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security).  I have some internally-developed binary modules that are stored on and executed from a network share.  To get .NET 2.0/PowerShell 2.0 to load them, I had added a URL rule to the `Intranet` code group to trust that directory:

```
PS> & "$Env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe" -machine -listgroups
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CasPol 2.0.50727.5420
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Security is ON
Execution checking is ON
Policy change prompt is ON

Level = Machine

Code Groups:

1.  All code: Nothing
    1.1.  Zone - MyComputer: FullTrust
        1.1.1.  StrongName - ...: FullTrust
        1.1.2.  StrongName - ...: FullTrust
    1.2.  Zone - Intranet: LocalIntranet
        1.2.1.  All code: Same site Web
        1.2.2.  All code: Same directory FileIO - 'Read, PathDiscovery'
        1.2.3.  Url - file://Server/Share/Directory/WindowsPowerShell/Modules/*: FullTrust
    1.3.  Zone - Internet: Internet
        1.3.1.  All code: Same site Web
    1.4.  Zone - Untrusted: Nothing
    1.5.  Zone - Trusted: Internet
        1.5.1.  All code: Same site Web
```

Note that, depending on which versions of .NET are installed and whether it's 32- or 64-bit Windows, [`caspol.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/tools/caspol-exe-code-access-security-policy-tool) can exist in the following locations, each with their own security configuration (`security.config`):

- `$Env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\`
- `$Env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\`
- `$Env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`
- `$Env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\`

After deleting group `1.2.3.`...

```bsh
PS> & "$Env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe" -machine -remgroup 1.2.3.
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CasPol 2.0.50727.9136
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The operation you are performing will alter security policy.
Are you sure you want to perform this operation? (yes/no)
yes
Removed code group from the Machine level.
Success
```

...I am left with the default CAS configuration and local scripts now work again.  It's been a while since I've tinkered with CAS, and I'm not sure why my rule would seem to interfere with those granting `FullTrust` to `MyComputer`, but since [CAS is deprecated as of .NET 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security-policy-compatibility-and-migration) (on which PowerShell 3.0 is based), I guess it's a moot point now.

Comment: How did you add a URL rule? I had the same issue and hoping this can help me solving it.  Thanks.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've worked with `caspol.exe`, but after running `caspol.exe -machine -addgroup 1.2 -url file://Server/Share/Directory/WindowsPowerShell/Modules/* FullTrust` I ended up with the same `1.2.3.` rule seen in this answer.  I was using a `file://` URL to reference a directory on an SMB share, though I see in the documentation one of the `-addgroup` [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/tools/caspol-exe-code-access-security-policy-tool#examples) uses a UNC path.

Comment: I dont have this internet thing on any of my 4 caspol.exe so this is not the solution

Comment: @Charkel What is the problem you're having?  The same one described in the question with the same error message?  This fixed the bizarre and unexpected behavior I was experiencing, which is why I marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 267):

Some things to check:

Can you change to unrestricted?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Is the group policy set?

- `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell`
- `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell`

Also, how are you calling Script.ps1?

Does this allow it to run?

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file .\Script.ps1
```

Comment: The default value for the `Scope` parameter is `LocalMachine`, so `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` is effectively the same as the `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine` I'd already tried.  Yes, the `Turn on Script Execution` policy is enabled for `Computer Configuration`.  `PowerShell` opens to `C:\Users\UserName`, so I just run `.\Desktop\Script.ps1` at the prompt.  Using the absolute path yields the same error, as does calling the script via `powershell.exe`.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the group policy setting and refreshing with `gpupdate /force`? (Relaunch PowerShell.exe after)

Comment: Well, for a long while I was running as `Unrestricted` at the `LocalMachine` scope, but when I started writing scripts I wanted to run from other computers I set `LocalMachine` back to `Undefined` and added the current Group Policy to set `RemoteSigned` at the `MachinePolicy` scope. This is just a one-off test script and it's really no big deal to run it from the network instead, I just want to know *why* it doesn't work locally. After all, a locally-created script should be allowed to execute under `RemoteSigned`, right? I just thought there must be something I'm missing or not understanding.

Comment: @BACON You are correct about `RemoteSigned` saving `Write-Host hi` with notepad to your desktop should run fine. You're configuration looks ok too... Something seems broken to me... which is why I suggested removing the group policy to see if it helps.

Answer (score 164):

Is the file being blocked? I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by right clicking the .PS1 file in Windows, selecting Properties, and choosing Unblock if that option appears at the bottom of the Properties tab.

Comment: As I explained, the script is being created directly on my hard drive (not downloaded from anywhere), and I confirmed there are no alternate streams identifying it as originating from a different zone (like Internet Explorer and other web browsers create).  If I run `'Write-Host ''Hello, World!'';' > .\Test.ps1; .\Test.ps1;` I still get the error that the script is not digitally signed and it is not executed.  If I open the Properties dialog for the newly-created file there is nothing to unblock.

Comment: Note that if you downloaded a zip file, you should unblock the zip file before extracting it to avoid mass-unblocking all the files inside it.

Answer (score 40):

When you run a .ps1 PowerShell script you might get the message saying “.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system.”
To fix it you have to run the command below to run Set-ExecutionPolicy and change the Execution Policy setting.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Comment: Another answer already suggests using the `Bypass` execution policy.  Using a different policy isn't helpful, anyways, and doesn't address the actual issue if `RemoteSigned` really is what's needed.  Finally, the error message you reference is not the same one as in the question.

Comment: Also, this command only works for the current session

Comment: Also, make sure that your PowerShell starts as Administrator

Comment: bingo! winner winner chicken dinner!

Answer (score 27):

I have found out when running a PS1 file for a Mapped drive to Dropbox that I'm always getting this error.  When opening up properties for the PS1 there is no "Unblock".

The only thing that work for me is

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file .\Script.ps1
```

Comment: You're saying your script is stored on a drive mapped to a network share?  Or the script creates a mapped drive?  If the former, as it states in the body and title of the question, the script was created and stored locally, so the origin/zone of the script would not be a factor.  Either way, using the `Bypass` execution policy has already been suggested [over five years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742897/150605) and as recently as [five months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061205/150605).  Please read the question and existing answers before answering.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, it does not work in Power shell and I had the problem when I was working with vs code so I used the terminal of vs code and then it worked :

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

This command sets the execution policy to bypass for only the current PowerShell session after the window is closed, the next PowerShell session will open running with the default execution policy.

see this link :
[main page](https://caiomsouza.medium.com/fix-for-powershell-script-not-digitally-signed-69f0ed518715)

Answer (score 0):

Select your terminal Command prompt instead of Power shell. That should work.

Comment: What does this even mean?  Select it where?  The goal was to run a PowerShell script in PowerShell, so using anything other than PowerShell would not work.

Comment: I had the same error trying to run AWS Amplify CLI. Running amplify command from WIndows Terminal instead of PowerShell seemed to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

This is an IDE issue. Change the setting in the PowerShell GUI. Go to the *Tools* tab and select Options, and then *Debugging options*. Then check the box *Turn off requirement for scripts to be signed*. Done.

Comment: The OP clearly does not want scripts to run unsigned, and did not refer to the IDE.

Comment: Not available in Powershell ISE

Answer (score -1):

In my case the error was showing also the article that needs to be checked on the MS site and it was correctly pointing to an example to set the execution policy for the user, which allowed me to enable the thing to work every time.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same issue and fixed it by changing the default program to open .ps1 files to PowerShell. It was set to [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29).

Comment: You did have this same issue?  Or when you'd double-click a `.ps1` file it'd open in Notepad instead of executing the script in PowerShell?

Comment: This a question about execution privileges _within_ PowerShell, not about OP thinking double-clicking the file will execute it.

Answer (score -2):

**Please make a backup for the script.bs1 file**

What works for me was deleting the script.bs1 file and running the execution command.

Comment: What is the error message you were getting that was solved by doing this?

Comment: I have gone through this error 2 different times and fix it the same way. It looks like running the execution command from the CMD will run immediately on the other file with the same name but with the extension (.cmd) .

Comment: File C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Script.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Script.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system.  ((Script.ps1 not digitally signed error))

Comment: I see.  And what is returned when you run `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`?

Comment: MachinePolicy AllSigned, UserPolicy Undefined, Process Undefined, CurrentUser RemoteSigned, LocalMachine Bypass

Comment: Well, your issue is that machine Group Policy (`MachinePolicy`) has set an execution policy of `AllSigned`, which, as the name implies, requires _everything_ to be signed regardless of origin.  This overrides the local machine and user policies of `RemoteSigned` and `Bypass`, respectively.  Your answer is very light on details as far as what exactly you've done, but I'm guessing you're deleting and recreating the script, which has the effect of unblocking it (or similar).  I still don't know how that'd end up overriding `MachinePolicy`, though, which takes precedence over all others.

Comment: bs1? This question is about PowerShell files, which are .ps1 files. Also, how could you run an execution command on a file if you just deleted the file? This answer does not seem to add any value to the question.

Answer (score -3):

Try running the Powershell GUI as Administrator

Comment: As stated in the question, `I am both a domain administrator and a local administrator`.  Running PowerShell elevated would not make a difference as the script was allowed to run unelevated when stored on a network share.

Answer (score -3):

This occurs due to Powershell execution policy is set to restricted by default which prevents execution PowerShell scripts and protects from running malicious scripts.

You can change execution scope for specific scope by running the following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process
```

Comment: It says right in the title of the question that the execution policy in use is `RemoteSigned`.

Answer (score -4):

**Instead of Powershell, you should use CMD to run scripts.** Powershell needs to have its execution policy enabled. Read more in [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.micros.com/it-it/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3).

Comment: This is a PowerShell question, not a CMD question.

Answer (score -5):

Run below 2 commands in PowerShell window

1. Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
2. Unblock-File -Path D:\PowerShell\Script.ps1