# I am trying to make ng serve but I got this error in terminal

Tags: angular, powershell

ng : File C:\Users\Jothi\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\Jothi Tamil\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 is not
digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy,
see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- ng --version
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my locally-created script not allowed to run under the RemoteSigned execution policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742775/why-is-my-locally-created-script-not-allowed-to-run-under-the-remotesigned-execu)

Comment: the link that you put here gives the answer. That's always a good start

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why am I suddenly getting: ng : File C:\Users\d\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72863930/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-ng-file-c-users-d-appdata-roaming-npm-ng-ps1-canno)

Answer (score 5):

You should invoke following command to change `ExecutionPolicy` to `RemoteSigned`. Because default policy is [Restricted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1#restricted), it prevents running of all script files.

```
$ Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: can it be possible? stackoverflow.com/questions/66288953

Answer (score 3):

1. Please open a command prompt
   run the following command

   **set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser**

   [image]
2. now run this command:

   **Get-ExecutionPolicy**

[image]

3. View policies, by running this command:

   **Get-ExecutionPolicy -list**
   [image]