# Why does sanity cli get error while install it?

Tags: node.js, powershell, next.js, sanity

I'm trying:

```
npm install -g @sanity/cli
>> sanity init --coupon javascriptmastery2022
```

and I get this message:

```
sanity : File C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\sanity.ps1 cannot be loaded. The 
file C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\sanity.ps1 is not digitally signed. You       
cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running      
scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:2 char:1
+ sanity init --coupon javascriptmastery2022
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why is my locally-created script not allowed to run under the RemoteSigned execution policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742775/why-is-my-locally-created-script-not-allowed-to-run-under-the-remotesigned-execu)?

Answer (score 0):

go to this link: [Execution Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/ar-sa/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2)

or copy this to the terminal:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```